# Typeorm throws an error due to Jest mocking

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, typeorm

I am trying to mock `typeorm` module using jest.

I am getting following error.

> TypeError: __1.getMetadataArgsStorage is not a function
>
> ```
>   at src/decorator/columns/Column.ts:149:13
>   at DecorateProperty (node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:553:33)
>   at Object.decorate (node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:123:24)
>   at Object.<anonymous>.__decorate (src/FakeEntity.ts:4:92)
> ```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-express-server-forked-87mx5?file=/src/FakeEntity.test.ts) reproduction.

To run the test just use codesanbox terminal and fire `npm run test` command.

I cant make it done, it seems like mocking does not work properly in this setup.It seems valid what `jest.requireActual("typeorm")` returns though.I am tinkering with this for quite a while.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution? If so, would you post it as an answer below? I have the same issue, and from what I can tell so far, this error happens in `node_modules/typeorm/decorator/columns/Column.ts` because at the time the `@Column` decorator is applied to the entity, `jest.mock('typeorm')` hasn't populated yet and contains an empty object that doesn't have the `getMetadataArgsStorage()` yet

Comment: [This comment led me to a solution](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-575177406).